# Setting up RefTeX Tab completion in emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I am trying to make <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion work with RefTeX. When typing <kbd>C-c [</kbd> and selecting the type of reference I have then a prompt in the minibuffer. When I know the beginning of the bib key I want to enter, say for instance `Campbell2006`, I would like to type `Camp` <kbd>Tab</kbd> and get Campbell2006 [sole completion].

I have managed to set it up for some documents but I do not understand exactly why it works for them and not for others. I have noticed that for the documents that have proper <kbd>Tab></kbd> completion, the following line is added to the file `name_of_tex_file.el` created in a `auto` subfolder:

```lisp
(TeX-add-style-hook "name_of_tex_file"
(lambda ()
(LaTeX-add-bibliographies
"absolute_path_to_bib")))
```

I think I obtained this results by adding `%%% reftex-default-bibliography: absolute_path_to_bib` at the end of my files but this is kind of a nuisance, especially when editing the same file on several computers.

Note that RefTeX is working because when I type <kbd>C-c [</kbd> `Camp` <kbd>Ret</kbd>, I get a list (sometime a bit odd) with the Campbell2006 entry.

I have tried to set the %BIBINPUTS% environment variables with no success.
Adding `(setq reftex-bibpath-environment-variables '("c:/path_to_bib_file/"))` seemed necessary for the <kbd>C-c [</kbd> `Camp` <kbd>Ret</kbd> method to work.
It has somehow the same defects as adding a `%%% reftex-default-bibliography:` to the end of the file and did not provided the <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion.

I have tried various combinations of `/`, `//`, `\\` and `\` as file separators when specifying files but I do not know exact which I should use (I'm using emacs in a windows environment). The issue might be as simple as that but as there are lots of parameters to try I fail do determine where is the problem.

What is the step-by-step method to make RefTeX work smoothly with bibliography, including the <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion?

EDIT:
Completion is possible according to the Reftex manual entry about the command `reftex-citation`:

> The regular expression uses an expanded syntax: `&&' is interpreted as and. Thus,`aaaa&&bbb' matches entries which contain both `aaaa' and`bbb'. **While entering the regexp, completion on knows [sic] citation keys is possible**. `=' is a good regular expression to match all entries in all files.

it does not provide precise guidance on how to make it work though.

Kindahero suggests setting a list of the bib entries and use the `completing-read` command. This sounds sensible, however I would like to generate this list automatically and it seems feasible because it works with some of my documents.

Comment: Just a hint. to be able to have `TAB` completion, you need to make a list with all your bib entries to make use of `completing-read` which indeed by default bound to `TAB`

Comment: As an alternative solution, you can type `=`, then in the selection buffer search for what you need.

Comment: For people interested, https://user42.tuxfamily.org/ac-tex-ref/index.html may be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of `reftex-citation` is a bit confusing. It promises completion on known citation keys but I believe "known" refers to keys that have been used previously in this session rather than all keys in the appropriate bibliography. You can use the `LaTeX-add-all-bibitems-from-bibtex` command defined below to load all keys in your bibliography:

```
(defun get-bibtex-keys (file)
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
    (mapcar 'car (bibtex-parse-keys))))

(defun LaTeX-add-all-bibitems-from-bibtex ()
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'LaTeX-add-bibitems
        (apply 'append
               (mapcar 'get-bibtex-keys (reftex-get-bibfile-list)))))
```

Suggestions on appropriate hooks to make this happen automatically are welcome.